# Problem installling CiviCRM on Drupal 10

Tags: installation

I am attempting to install CiviCRM on a Drupal 10 website. The composer instructions seem to have downloaded the software just fine, and it all looks reasonable, but when I put in
cv core:install --cms-base-url="https://dev,wis.communty" --db="mysql://myusername:mypassword@localhost:3306/dev_civicrm"

I get back the error Failed to parse or find a CMS null

I am not at all sure what that is telling me or how to proceed.

## If I run it in verbose mode I get:
Box Requirements Checker

> Using PHP 8.1.27
> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
> /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.ini

> Checking Box requirements:
> ✔ The application requires a version matching ">=7.3.0".
> ✔ The application requires the extension "json".
> ✔ The package "psy/psysh" requires the extension "json".
> ✔ The package "nikic/php-parser" requires the extension "tokenizer".
> ✔ The package "psy/psysh" requires the extension "tokenizer".

[OK] Your system is ready to run the application.

[BootTrait:debug] Call CMS bootstrap
[CmsBootstrap:debug] Options: {
"env": "CIVICRM_BOOT",
"search": true,
"httpHost": "localhost",
"user": null,
"output": {}
}
[CmsBootstrap:debug] Find CMS...
[CmsBootstrap:debug] CMS: null

In CmsBootstrap.php line 66:

[Exception]
Failed to parse or find a CMS null

Exception trace:
at phar:///home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/extern/cv.phar/lib/src/CmsBootstrap.php:66
Civi\Cv\CmsBootstrap->bootCms() at phar:///home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/extern/cv.phar/lib/src/Util/BootTrait.php:100
Civi\Cv\Command\CoreInstallCommand->_boot_cms_only() at phar:///home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/extern/cv.phar/src/Util/SetupCommandTrait.php:22
Civi\Cv\Command\CoreInstallCommand->bootSetupSubsystem() at phar:///home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/extern/cv.phar/src/Command/CoreInstallCommand.php:47
Civi\Cv\Command\CoreInstallCommand->execute() at phar:///home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/extern/cv.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:127
Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/extern/cv.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:637
Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/extern/cv.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:190
Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/extern/cv.phar/src/Application.php:67
Civi\Cv\Application->doRun() at phar:///home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/extern/cv.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:101
Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/extern/cv.phar/src/Application.php:33
Civi\Cv\Application::main() at phar:///home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/extern/cv.phar/bin/cv:28
require() at /home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/extern/cv.phar:14
require() at /home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/vendor/civicrm/cli-tools/bin/cv:7
include() at /home/wis/domains/dev.wis.community/public_html/bin/cv:119

core:install [--settings-path [SETTINGS-PATH]] [--setup-path [SETUP-PATH]] [--src-path [SRC-PATH]] [--plugin-path [PLUGIN-PATH]] [--cms-base-url [CMS-BASE-URL]] [--lang [LANG]] [--comp [COMP]] [--ext [EXT]] [--db [DB]] [-m|--model [MODEL]] [-A|--abort] [-K|--keep] [-f|--force] [--debug-event [DEBUG-EVENT]] [--debug-model] [--level LEVEL] [--hostname HOSTNAME] [-t|--test] [-U|--user USER]

Answer (score 3):

Oops.  Found the problem.  I somehow had a comma in the url rather than a period.  Worked fine after I fixed that.